# How to use OKHTTP to make a post request in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I need to make a post request to an endpoint from my android project. I am using Kotlin. Will I need to create a separate OKHttpClient Class for this.

Comment: you can use this response : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45219917/5901637

Comment: if you need other information, just let me to know

Comment: "Will I need to create a separate OKHttpClient Class for this" -- usually no. See [the OkHttp recipes](http://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#posting-form-parameters) for things like how to make POST requests. Their samples are in Java but should be fairly straightforward to translate to Kotlin.

Comment: @HaniyehKhaksar I have referred that before asking the question. I think that doesn't say anything in particular about the post request. I am trying to make it and currently stuck here
  "val request = Request.Builder().url(url).post(userLoginCredentials).build()"

the userLoginCredentials is a custom object and it says it needs ResponseBody() object. 
I one tutorial it says you can create ResponseBody Object with ResponseBody.create() but now it is depreceated

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's how you can achieve this:

```
val payload = "test payload"

val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient()
val requestBody = payload.toRequestBody()
val request = Request.Builder()
        .post(requestBody)
        .url("url")
        .build()
okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
    override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
        // Handle this
    }

    override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
        // Handle this
    }
})
```

Don't forget to import:

```
import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.toRequestBody
```

Comment: The import was what I was missing. I was attempting to use String.toRequestBody but it wasn't resolving.

Comment: Version? for 3.12.1 is not working, or I just need to add something else to make it work?

Comment: This answer was meant for OkHttp3 4.x+

Comment: the "Companion" part of the import is not resolved and I cannot figure ot why, any help?

Comment: @MarcoOttina now you have to create the request body with `create` method `val body: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(JSON, refreshToken)`. You can see a full example at [https://github.com/square/okhttp#handling-authentication](https://github.com/square/okhttp#handling-authentication)